# How to set an admin password with passport node

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js

This website is only going to have admin users, I have created the schema, the registration view and the route, however something is bad with the logic in the route.

/register page only have three inputs, username, password and email address. At the moment, if the user uses any random password to enter, is showing a flash error saying the password is not valid and redirecting me to the landing page, however, it is still creating the new user in the database.

Also, if the user uses the right password same thing as above is happening.
What am I doing wrong?
here is my code:

Schema

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String, 
        unique: true, 
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String, 
        unique: true, 
        required: true, 
        lowercase: true,
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
   // isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false, required:true}
});
```

Register view

```
<form class="form-group" action="/register" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control mb-1" type="text" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control mb-3" type="password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info w-100">Register!</button>
</form>
```

Route

```
// register route
router.get("/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render("register", {page: "register"});
});
// handle sign up logic
router.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email
    });

    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render("register", {error: err.message});
        } else {
            if(req.body.password !== process.env.ADMIN_CODE) {
                req.flash('error', 'the password is not valid');
                res.redirect("/");     
            } else {
                passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                    req.flash("success", "Great! Welcome! " + req.body.username);
                    res.redirect("/"); 
                });
            }   
        }  
    });
});
```

Comment: you're creating the user before checking the password.

Comment: Also, do you *really* want all your admin users sharing the same password?

Comment: There is only going to be two admin users, which can create new content or delete stuff, there is no other kind of user. They could have their own password but what is important for me is that the logic dont create any user if the ADMIN_CODE is not the same

Comment: I have modified the route, putting the condition "if req.password.body !== ADMIN_CODE then redirect" just after User.register, is redirecting but again creates the user o.O @DanO

Comment: you are still creating the user before checking the password.